# Run two functions in parallel in Python

Tags: python-3.x, concurrency, multiprocessing, raspberry-pi4, process-pool

Currently I have a program which scans all the available ble devices and then updates it to a list bt_addrs. This list is then passed to a function named data() which performs the work. To go over all the elements in the list I have used ProcessPoolExecutor.

One issue that I am facing is the scanning happens only for one time and then it stops. I want to make the scanning function to execute continuously so that if any new device comes in the vicinity, it will get added to the list and list should get updated and data function should work on that updated list in parallel.

Having an intermediate knowledge about Python and multiprocessing is an advance topic , a help would definitely help me increase my knowledge and help me get the desired results of the whole program.
If you have any other approach, please tell.

I am running this code on Raspberry Pi 4- quad core Arm v8 processor, python version 3.7.3

Below is the code I currently have

```
import sys
import time
from bluepy import btle
from bluepy.btle import Scanner
import concurrent.futures
import signal


bt_addrs = []

def data(mac_adrs3):
    
     while True:
    // main works happen here
    

def main():
    scanner = Scanner()   # scanner ovject
    devices = scanner.scan(30.0)    # scans for 30 sec 
    available_devices=[]
    for dev in devices:
        available_devices.append(dev.addr)   # all the MAC address are stored
    
    bt_addrs = available_devices
    

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        executor.map(data,bt_addrs)             #data fun runs on all the elements in list bt_addrs

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow")! As currently structured, your question is too broad and are not a good fit for this site. Since there are multiple approaches, answers will likely be based more on opinion rather than data driven. Give a good read over [Where to Start](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), and  [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") then edit your post.

Comment: I hope this is as per the guidelines. if not do correct me !

Comment: Any answers or suggestions will be helpful ! Still stuck at this problem